# EB CLI "eb create" ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform ARN is invalid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create an Elastic Beanstalk node.js environment via the EB CLI. I've ran `eb init` in my code repo, and this doesn't give me any issues.

Next, when I run `eb create` to create the environment, I receive the error `ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform ARN is invalid: Not an IAM ARN: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.15.2 running Node.js.`

I've searched for this error, it seems like I need to update the platform version, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I also downgraded my node version from v12.18.4 to v12.18.3 because the EB docs didn't say that v12.18.4 was supported.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can just run:

```
eb platform select
```

to [select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-platform.html#eb3-platform-environment) new default platform. Nevertheless, your platform seems fine as it is current one as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs). Thus there maybe something else causing this error. But still maybe worth changing or re-selecting the platform version.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I will try this in the future. I ended up just creating the environment in the EB console instead of the CLI.

Comment: @awebdev No problem. You can answer your own question if you want, or accept my, as it seems that the issue is solved. Otherwise, the question will keep appearing in [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elastic-beanstalk?tab=Unanswered) section prompting others to provide answers which seem to be not needed currently.

Comment: This was it for me and should be labeled as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a very similar issue with a Python project containing a `Dockerfile`.

Inside the project I ran `eb create --database` (version `EB CLI 3.19.3`).

It prompted me to pick an environment name and DNS CNAME prefix, which was fine.

It then asked to `Select a load balancer type`.

I picked the default, which is `2` (`application`).

As soon as I hit enter, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform ARN is invalid: Not an IAM ARN: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.4 running Docker.
```

Following [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin)'s [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093978/15282257) I ran `eb platform select`.

It prompted me about Docker:

```
It appears you are using Docker. Is this correct?
(Y/n): y
```

It then prompted me to select a platform:

```
Select a platform branch.
1) Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
2) Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux
3) Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux
(default is 1): 1
```

This solved the problem.

Even though this is (seemingly) the same setup that was picked by default, `eb create --database` worked without the error afterwards, and even `eb status` show

```
Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.4
```

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question. The author encountered the exact InvalidParameterError that the OP specified and confirmed the correct way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

`eb platform select` - overrides the default platform. In cases, where you want to create an environment that uses a different platform than default one, we can simply provide `-p` or `--provide` then the platform.

I was able to successfully do it by running the following command using nodev16 platform
`eb create --platform "Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2"`

Answer (score -2):

I ended up creating the environment in the EB console instead of the CLI. The environment was created successfully from here.

Comment: Your answer did not solve the problem. Consider marking the "eb platform select" as the correct answer.

Comment: Updated to the correct answer.